# Hello,I am new to VHDL and came across a line which is as shown below

Tags: vhdl

```
signal a: unsigned(15 downto 0) := to_unsigned(10100, 16);
```

If I'm not wrong its a syntax for converting integer to unsigned numbers but I can't figure out whats the use of `to_unsigned(10100, 16)`, especially that number **10100**.

Comment: 10100 is something called a "magic number" which should be replaced by a named constant, the name explaining exactly what it does, e.g. `constant everest_height_in_metres : natural := 10100;`

Comment: @BrianDrummond Isn't it the height of Mauna Kea (Hawaii, USA), measured from the ocean bed, is it?

Comment: 10100 is a numerical literal, which is base 10 by default and represents the number being converted to an unsigned value as an array of std_ulogic length 16 (15 downto 0).  The 16 is how long the length of the converted value should be. The assignment in declaration provides the default value, which in this case will be "0010011101110100".  And as we see people are busily looking for a meaning to ascribe to x"2774".

Comment: Your title should explain your problem

Comment: @Paebbels : thus demonstrating how easily a named constant exposes a bug!

Answer (score 0):

The line to_unsigned(10100, 16) will convert the integer value (in base 10) 10100 into a 16 bit unsigned signal.

An integer value can not easily be synthesized into logic, and you'll often see it converted to unsigned, signed or std_logic_vector before any bitmanibulation is being done to it.

You will however often use integer, or derivatives hereof, internal in the modules for stuff like counter etc, as they are easier to understand and are faster to perform calculations on for the simulator.